# C Language: Search text file for a "var" and store the next string as the value

Tags: c, string, search, scanf, fgets

How can I do the following task:

```
file = fopen("filename","r");
search_word_int( "var1" , file , 1 );
search_word_int( "var2" , file , 1 );
...
fclose(file);
```

I have used:

```
int search_word_int( char *word , FILE *file , int *step )
{
    char dummy[256];
    int variable = 0, step_ = step;
    while( (fgets( dummy , 256 , file )) != NULL )
    {
        if( strcmp( dummy , word ) != 0 )
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < step_ + 1 ; i++)
                fscanf( file , "%d" , &variable );
            printf("%s is found = %d\n",word,variable);
            return(variable);
        }
    }
}
```

as the *search function* but it seems that fgets does not search from the beginning of the file, instead it continues to get next lines after the last call!

Answer (score 0):

Each FILE has a file position or offset, and when you perform a fgets(), the position is moved forward. If you wish to read from the beginning of the file, insert the following line in the beginning of your search_word_int() function to move the file offset to the beginning of the file:

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: I did as your answer, but the return value is not true. I see that only the second line (which is the value of first variable) is returned every time I search for a variable! If text file is "var1 10 var2 3 var3 7", then I only take 10 each time I search for var1, var2, and var3 !

Comment: I think the compare function (strcmp) does not work correctly ! Any idea?

Comment: strcmp works fine, when you interpret its return correctly. https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp

Comment: What's wrong here is the logic of the code. strcmp() returns a non-negative value if the two strings compared are of different length. So the if statement will always be executed! What you want is to set the size of dummy to strlen(word) and set the condition to strcmp(dummy,word) == 0

Comment: OK, I set strcmp(dummy,word) == 0, but how do I set size of dummy, would you please give sample code ? Thanks.

Comment: char dummy[strlen(word)]

Comment: With changing to strcmp(dummy,word) == 0, it does not pass through if statement.

Comment: Ah, my bad, if you would change the code to char dummy[strlen(word) + 1] to account for the null terminating character.

Comment: OK, I changed the code to 'char dummy[strlen(word) + 1]', but still does not pass through if statement.

Comment: You should also change to fgets(dummy, strlen(word) + 1), file)